# difference between creating server via nova and heat

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

What are the pros and cons of creating server via [nova](https://docs.openstack.org/api-ref/compute/#create-server) and [heat stack](https://docs.openstack.org/api-ref/orchestration/v1/#create-stack)?

When should we use `nova` and when we should use `heat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Heat to create applications that consist of several resources like instances, networks, volumes, software configurations etc., in particular if you want to repeat the launch of these applications or parameterize the launch.

In fact, the paragraph [Heat's purpose and vision](https://docs.openstack.org/heat/latest/) describes it much better than I can.

Use Nova directly if you just want to launch a single instance or a group of instances.

By the way, the links *nova* and *heat stack* in your question point to the same URL.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the link.